# center relativeLayout in linearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've a linear layout with inside 3 different relative layout.I want to divide in 3 equals parts this root linear layout.I've set the weight sum to 3 in linear layout and set to 0 the width for each relative.But when i hide one of this relative,the other two are not centered as expected.This is the xml code `

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/OffertaBassa"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/offertaPiuBassa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_offerta_migliore"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_gabriele_testo"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/PrezzoBasso"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/offertaPiuBassa"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="€"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_drawer_listItem_selected"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ivaEsclusaLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/PrezzoBasso"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
                    android:text="IVA esclusa"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_card_text_light"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/NumeroPreventivi"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preventiviRicevuti"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_preventivi_ricevuti"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_gabriele_testo"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numeroPreventivi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/preventiviRicevuti"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
                    android:text="N°"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_card_text"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/prezzoriferimento"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prezzoRiferimento"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_prezzo_riferimento"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_gabriele_testo"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prezzoDiriferimento"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/prezzoRiferimento"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
                    android:text="€"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_card_text"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/prezzoDiriferimento"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
                    android:text="IVA esclusa"
                    android:textColor="@color/macingo_card_text_light"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>`
```

How can i solve this situation?I've tried to set gravity but with no result.
Thanks

Comment: You need center vertical or horizontal?

Comment: horizontal...in fact i've set width to 0 in each relative

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Please go through this Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/OffertaBassa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offertaPiuBassa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_offerta_migliore"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PrezzoBasso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/offertaPiuBassa"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="€"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ivaEsclusaLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PrezzoBasso"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="IVA esclusa"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/NumeroPreventivi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preventiviRicevuti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_preventivi_ricevuti"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numeroPreventivi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/preventiviRicevuti"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="N°"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/prezzoriferimento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prezzoRiferimento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="scheda_dettaglio_richiesta_prezzo_riferimento"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prezzoDiriferimento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/prezzoRiferimento"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="€"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/prezzoDiriferimento"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="IVA esclusa"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i've already test this solution before write here,and i don't have the 3 relative layout with the same width...i've try also to insert every relative in another linear layout with no result...

Answer (score -1):

You have to visibility gone of Relative layout.

```
NumeroPreventivi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

have you visibility gone or invisible of Relative Layout?because if you doing visibility gone of layout then its work perfectly and if you are doing visibility invisible then this layout existence true. i mean this layout take area of layout.

at run time you have to change weight sum of layouts.